# I need nvl (the oracle replace null values function) in cassandra using UDF

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

I need nvl  (the oracle replace null values function)  in cassandra using UDF. New to cassandra UDFs, so Can any one share the UDF for nvl in cassandra for replacing null values in tables.

Comment: which version of cassandra you are using... keep only the relevant one in tags

Comment: i'm using cql_version 3.4.0 and release_version 3.0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something similar to below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom_nvl ( val1 double, default_val double ) 
CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
RETURNS double LANGUAGE java AS 
'return (val1 == null)
            ? default_val
            : val1;';
```

literal for `default_val` is only possible in cassandra 3.8 and above.

If you need to return constant value and are using cassandra version less than 3.8 then use something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom_udf ( val1 double) 
CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
RETURNS double LANGUAGE java AS 
'return (val1 == null)
            ? 2.0
            : val1;';
```

To use `UDF` you should set `enable_user_defined_functions` to `true` in `cassandra.yaml`.

Though `UDF` can only be used in `SELECT` statements.

**Note:** literal values in UDF are supported from cassandra 3.8 [CASSANDRA-10783](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10783)

[UDF in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDF.html)

[More on UDF](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/user-defined-functions-in-cassandra-3-0)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your Reply. I have created this UDF and working on it right now. while executing this below query, "select ca_available_limit,cvm.custom_nvl(cvm.customer_ca_details.ca_average_halfyearly_balance,2) from cvm.customer_ca_details;"  i'm getting
"com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:95 no viable alternative at input '2' (...cvm.custom_nvl(cvm.customer_ca_details.ca_average_halfyearly_balance,[2]...)"  this error.

Comment: Literal values in cassandra are supported from cassandra 3.8.... you need to hardcode return value in UDF if null value is found and are using version less than 3.8

Comment: Ya , its working fine, after hardcoded the  return value.. Thank you, Way to go!!!